# GHDL Simulator: numeric_std-body.v93: NUMERIC_STD."=": null argument detected, returning FALSE

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to simulation my VHDL code using the GHDL simulator and the simulator produces many warning messages from "numeric_std" library, I was trying to remember what causes these errors and how to prevent them from appearing in GHDL simulator.  Is it possible to modify the code to prevent them or to add a simulator flag or add a pragma to the code? :

```
numeric_std-body.v93:1605:7:@0ms:(assertion warning): NUMERIC_STD."=": null argument detected, returning FALSE
```

Windows Run Script:

```
..\simtools\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe -a bus_fifo_mem.vhdl
..\simtools\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe -a bus_fifo.vhdl
..\simtools\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe -e bus_fifo
..\simtools\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe -r bus_fifo

numeric_std-body.v93:1605:7:@0ms:(assertion warning): NUMERIC_STD."=": null argument detected, returning FALSE
```

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity bus_fifo is
    generic(
        DEPTH_WIDTH               : integer := 0;
        DATA_WIDTH                : integer := 0
    );
    port(
        clk         : in    std_logic;
        rst         : in    std_logic;
        wr_data_i   : in    std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        wr_en_i     : in    std_logic;
        rd_data_o   : out   std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        rd_en_i     : in    std_logic;
        full_o      : out   std_logic;
        empty_o     : out   std_logic        
    );
end entity;
architecture rtl of bus_fifo is
    constant   DW                        : integer := DATA_WIDTH;
    constant   AW                        : integer := DEPTH_WIDTH;
    signal     write_pointer             : unsigned(AW downto 0);
    signal     read_pointer              : unsigned(AW downto 0);
    signal     empty_int                 : std_logic;
    signal     full_or_empty             : std_logic;
begin

    process(write_pointer, read_pointer)
    begin
        if (write_pointer(AW) = read_pointer(AW)) then
            empty_int <= '1';
        else 
            empty_int <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;


    process(write_pointer, read_pointer)
    begin
        if (write_pointer(AW-1 downto 0) = read_pointer(AW-1 downto 0)) then
            full_or_empty <= '1';
        else 
            full_or_empty <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;

    full_o  <= full_or_empty and not empty_int;
    empty_o <= full_or_empty and empty_int;

    process(clk)
    begin   
        if (wr_en_i = '1') then
            write_pointer <= write_pointer + 1;
        end if;

        if (rd_en_i = '1') then
            read_pointer <= read_pointer + 1;
        end if;

        if (rst = '1') then
            read_pointer  <= (others => '0');
            write_pointer <= (others => '0');
        end if;
    end process;

    bus_fifo_mem: entity work.bus_fifo_mem
        generic map(
            ADDR_WIDTH    => AW,
            DATA_WIDTH    => DW,
            ENABLE_BYPASS => 1
        )
        port map(
            clk         => clk,
            dout        => rd_data_o,
            raddr       => std_logic_vector(read_pointer(AW-1 downto 0)),
            re          => rd_en_i,
            waddr       => std_logic_vector(write_pointer(AW-1 downto 0)),
            we          => wr_en_i,
            din         => wr_data_i
        );

end architecture;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity bus_fifo_mem is
    generic(
        ADDR_WIDTH     : integer := 32;
        DATA_WIDTH     : integer := 32;
        ENABLE_BYPASS  : integer := 1
    );
    port(
        clk    : in    std_logic;
        raddr  : in    std_logic_vector(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        re     : in    std_logic;
        waddr  : in    std_logic_vector(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        we     : in    std_logic;
        din    : in    std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        dout   : out   std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0)        
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of bus_fifo_mem is
    signal     rdata  : std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal     din_r  : std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal     bypass : std_logic;

    -- VERILOG
    --reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] mem[(1<<ADDR_WIDTH)-1:0];

    type mem_type is array (integer'(2) ** ADDR_WIDTH - 1 downto 0) 
          of std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);

    signal mem : mem_type := (others => (others => '0'));

begin

process(clk)
begin
    if (clk = '1' and clk'event) then

        if (we = '1') then
            mem(to_integer(unsigned(waddr))) <= din;
        end if;

        if (re = '1') then
           rdata <= mem(to_integer(unsigned(raddr)));
        end if;

    end if;
end process;


end architecture;
```

Answer (score 1):

For GHDL simulator see --run-help:

.. option:: --ieee-asserts<=POLICY>

Select how the assertions from `ieee` units are
handled. `POLICY` can be `enable` (the default),
`disable` which disables all assertions from `ieee` packages
and `disable-at-0` which disables only at the start of simulation.

This option can be useful to avoid assertion messages from
`ieee.numeric_std` (and other `ieee` packages).

```
# PowerShell Build Script
class build {
    [Void] static info1([string]$msg) {
        write-host -background DarkBlue -foreground yellow $msg
    }
    [Void] static info2([string]$msg) {
        write-host -background DarkBlue -foreground cyan $msg
    }

    [void] static read ([string]$file) {
        $GHDL="..\simtools\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe"

        [build]::info2("")
        [build]::info2("GHDL ANALYSIS: " + $file)
        & $GHDL "-a" $file
    }

    [void] static elab ([string]$unit) {
        $GHDL="..\simtools\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe"

        [build]::info2("")
        [build]::info2("GHDL ELAB: " + $unit)
        & $GHDL "-e" $unit
    }

    [void] static run ([string]$unit) {
        $GHDL="..\simtools\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe"

        [build]::info2("")
        [build]::info2("GHDL RUN: " + $unit)
        & $GHDL "-r" $unit "--ieee-asserts=disable-at-0"
    }

}

# RTL Design
[build]::read("bus_fifo_mem.vhdl")
[build]::read("bus_fifo.vhdl")

[build]::elab("bus_fifo")
[build]::run("bus_fifo")
```

Answer (score 0):

For GHDL here's a powershell script that supposely turns off those VHDL messages:

```
class build {
    [Void] static info1([string]$msg) {
        write-host -background DarkBlue -foreground yellow $msg
    }
    [Void] static info2([string]$msg) {
        write-host -background DarkBlue -foreground cyan $msg
    }

    [void] static read ([string]$file) {
        $GHDL="..\simtools\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe"

        [build]::info2("")
        [build]::info2("GHDL ANALYSIS: " + $file)
        & $GHDL "-a" $file
        [build]::info1(" $GHDL -a " + $file)
    }

    [void] static elab ([string]$unit) {
        $GHDL="..\simtools\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe"

        [build]::info2("")
        [build]::info2("GHDL ELAB: " + $unit)
        & $GHDL "-e" $unit
        [build]::info1(" $GHDL -e " + $unit)
    }

    [void] static run ([string]$unit) {
        $GHDL="..\simtools\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe"

        [build]::info2("")
        $cmd = "$GHDL ""-r"" $unit ""--ieee-asserts=disable-at-0"" ""--vcd=ghdl_waves.vcd"" " 
        [build]::info2("GHDL RUN: " + $unit)
        [build]::info1("$cmd")
        & $GHDL "-r" $unit "--ieee-asserts=disable-at-0" "--vcd=ghdl_waves.vcd" "--stop-time=1us" "--disp-time"
    }

}

# RTL Design
[build]::read("hello.vhdl")
[build]::elab("hello")
[build]::run("hello")
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how to disable this warning in GHDL simulator...

Its because at 0 ns, I am performing to_integer on an invalid value (probably "UUUU"). A few of these warnings are expected, until you have reset your design, and don't indicate anything wrong. But if you get them after resetting, you have a problem.

"The warnings can be suppressed. IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8.5.2 Allowable modifications para 2 (in part) The package bodies for the NUMERIC_BIT and NUMERIC_STD packages declare a constant named NO_WARNING that has the value FALSE. A user may set NO_WARNING to TRUE and reanalyze the package body to suppress warning messages generated by calls to the functions in these packages. or in modelsim.ini uncomment or set NumericStdNoWarnings = 1. They are caused by metavalues present in a signed or unsigned with their binary value being evaluated, typically at initialization. Look to your component."

```
Package numeric_std is
...
end numeric_std;

Package body numeric_std is
   ...
   constant NO_WARNING : boolean := FALSE;  -- default to emit warnings
   ...
end numeric_std;
```

Actually I can fix this warning message in code by changing the defaults from zero to: (DEPTH_WIDTH : integer := 2; DATA_WIDTH : integer := 2) then checking that the unsigned signals are not undefined "x" by using function "is_X(…)"  … I just don't know if the following code is synthesizable:

```
    process(write_pointer, read_pointer)
    begin
        if (is_X(write_pointer) or is_X(read_pointer)) then         
            empty_int <= 'U';

        elsif (write_pointer(AW) = read_pointer(AW)) then
            empty_int <= '1';
        else 
            empty_int <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;


    process(write_pointer, read_pointer)
    begin
        if (is_X(write_pointer) or is_X(read_pointer) then          
            full_or_empty <= 'U';

        elsif (write_pointer(AW-1 downto 0) = read_pointer(AW-1 downto 0)) then
            full_or_empty <= '1';

        else 
            full_or_empty <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
```

Comment: Not correct. A null argument occurs because you have an array with length 0. I see the defaults for Addr and Data width are 0 - this will give you 0 length arrays for address and data, causing the warning.

Comment: nice catch.  So I changed the defaults from zero to: (DEPTH_WIDTH : integer := 2; DATA_WIDTH : integer := 2)… now the warning message changes to: " NUMERIC_STD."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE"